# How to randomly create and assign variables and shorten an if-else statement (Java android)

Tags: java, android, variable-assignment

I was wondering how to shorten my code by automatically creating and assigning variables for `TextView`s. Also, how do you shorten these `if-else` statements? I have looked at other threads, but they haven't fulfilled my needs. I am using Android Studio for this.

Here is my Java code:

```
package com.example.ani.testproject;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Random;


public class MainScreen extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);
    final TextView spot1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.spot1);
    final TextView spot2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.spot2);
    final TextView spot3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.spot3);
    final TextView spot4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.spot4);
    final TextView spot5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.spot5);
    final TextView spot6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.spot6);
    final TextView spot7 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.spot7);
    final TextView spot8 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.spot8);
    final TextView spot9 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.spot9);
    final TextView spot10 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.spot10);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick (View v) {
            int loopnum = 1;
            while(loopnum<4){
                Random r = new Random();
                int spotnumber = r.nextInt(11-1) + 1;
                if(spotnumber==1){
                    spot1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                }
                else if(spotnumber==2){
                    spot2.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                }
                else if(spotnumber==3){
                    spot3.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                }
                else if(spotnumber==4){
                    spot4.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                }
                else if(spotnumber==5){
                    spot5.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                }
                else if(spotnumber==6){
                    spot6.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                }
                else if(spotnumber==7){
                    spot7.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                }
                else if(spotnumber==8){
                    spot8.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                }
                else if(spotnumber==9){
                    spot9.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                }
                else if(spotnumber==10){
                    spot10.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                }
                loopnum += 1;
                SystemClock.sleep(5000);
            }
        }
    });



}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main_screen, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

I was not really able to show this clearly, but the last bracket corresponds to the bracket in:

```
public class MainScreen extends ActionBarActivity {
```

Here is my XML code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation = "horizontal">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="170dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation = "vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop = "5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight = "5dp"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:id = "@+id/spot1"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:id = "@+id/spot2"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:id = "@+id/spot3"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:id = "@+id/spot4"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:id = "@+id/spot5"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"/>


</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="170dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation = "vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginTop = "5dp"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout2">

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Press Me"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_gravity="right" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:id = "@+id/spot6"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight = "true"
        android:background="#ffffff"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:id = "@+id/spot7"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight = "true"
        android:background="#ffffff"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:id = "@+id/spot8"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight = "true"
        android:background="#ffffff"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:id = "@+id/spot9"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight = "true"
        android:background="#ffffff"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:id = "@+id/spot10"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight = "true"
        android:background="#ffffff"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Please help me! I am new to Android and Java.

Comment: http://www.7solutions.in/2013/06/how-to-generate-random-number-for.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like keeping a List of `TextView`s, rather than individual variables for each, would be appropriate in your case. We can use an `ArrayList`, and populate it by retrieving the IDs for the `TextView`s from their names specified in the layout xml.

```
ArrayList<TextView> spots = new ArrayList<TextView>();

for(int i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
    int id = getResources().getIdentifier("spot" + i, "id", getPackageName());
    spots.add((TextView) findViewById(id));
}
```

This will greatly simplify the other section of code, in that we now don't need any `if`s at all.

```
Random r = new Random();
int spotnumber = r.nextInt(10);
spots.get(spotnumber).setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I took my problem to a mentor, and he told me that I can use Layout.getChildAt(i). In this case, I will just hard code all of the TextViews in XML.

Comment: @AniPandu Yep, definitely another possibility. Just make sure to check that the child Views are the ones you want (e.g., not that Button), and do note that if you move stuff around in your layout, it might affect their order when iterating over them with `getChildAt()`. Glad you got it figured out. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to shorten you if => else if statements, you can use a switch statement.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Basically you give the switch a variable and then a set of case scenarios depending of the value of the given variable. In your case it would look like this :

```
switch (spotnumber) {
case 1 : //case scenario with spotnumber = 1
   spot1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
   break;
case 2 :  //case scenario with spotnumber = 2
   spot2.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
   break;
}
```

Don't forget the "break" otherwise each statement after the matching scenario will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution could be using Dependency Injection.You could look into [RoboGuice](https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice).
However Android best practices does not recommen this method.You could maybe just automate your function and store the textViews using an arraylist.

```
List<TextView> spotList= new ArrayList<TextView>();

for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    int id = getResources().getIdentifier("spot" + i, "id", getPackageName());
    spotList.add((TextView) findViewById(id));
}
```

and the if-else statement would be modified by using a switch case:

```
switch (spotnumber) {
case 1 : //equivalent of spotnumber==1
   spot1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
   break;
case 2 :  //equivalent of if spotnumber==2
   spot2.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
   break;
. 
.
.
}
```